# DraftJs : Custom button to add custom HTML + CSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

Using [DraftJs](https://draftjs.org/) with [WYSWYG](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/): I need to create a custom button in the toolbar. On clicking the button, some custom HTML (which includes `<button>`) is added to the content itself.

I know how to add a custom button, the docs are there. The button gets added and onclick I call the defined method `insertText`. But with `insertText`(a method in the DraftModifier class of draft.js) it only seems to add my HTML code as a string. Is there a different method I should use to add custom HTML into the content. I want to add real HTML.

Here is the TS declaration:

```
  static insertText(
    contentState: ContentState,
    targetRange: SelectionState,
    text: string,
    inlineStyle?: DraftInlineStyle,
    entityKey?: string
  ): ContentState;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [replaceWithFragment](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-modifier#replacewithfragment). To build the fragment you want to insert, first convert the string to HTML blocks with the utility `convertFromHTML`

```js
    const htmlContent = convertFromHTML(text);
```

then, use another utility to pass the array of content blocks to a map

```js
    const htmlContentMap = BlockMapBuilder.createFromArray(
      htmlContent.contentBlocks
    );
```

and call `replaceWithFragment` the same way you were calling `insertText`, but with the map of HTML content you built

```js
    const newContent = Modifier.replaceWithFragment(
      currentContent,
      currentSelection,
      htmlContentMap
    );
```

**UPDATE**

DraftJS doesn't support the button tag by default but you can add it as a [custom block render](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-custom-block-render-map)

first, create a map of types by merging the default supported tags with the button tag

```js
import {
...
  DefaultDraftBlockRenderMap,
...
} from "draft-js";

...
const mapWithButton = Map({
  button: {
    element: "button"
  }
}).merge(DefaultDraftBlockRenderMap);
...
```

and pass it as the third argument to the `convertFromHTML` function

```js
    const htmlContent = convertFromHTML(
      text,
      undefined,
      mapWithButton
    );
```

create a custom block renderer function and pass it to the Editor

```js
function myBlockRenderer(contentBlock: ContentBlock) {
  const type = contentBlock.getType();
  if (type === "button") {
    return {
      component: () => {
        return (
          <button onClick={() => console.log("doesn't seem to work :(")}>
            {contentBlock.getText()}
          </button>
        );
      },
      editable: false,
    };
  }
}
...
          <Editor
            ...
            customBlockRenderFunc={myBlockRenderer}
          />
```

It kind of works because it shows the button, although sometimes when there is text before the point when you insert it, it merges the previous text with the button text without showing the button. The click doesn't work either probably because of [this](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-block-components/#recommendations-and-other-notes)

> If your custom block renderer requires mouse interaction, it is often
> wise to temporarily set your Editor to readOnly={true} during this
> interaction. In this way, the user does not trigger any selection
> changes within the editor while interacting with the custom block.

https://codesandbox.io/s/insert-html-draftjs-73rmc?file=/src/Editor.tsx

Comment: Thanks for this. Especially for the codesandbox to make it easier. I need to insert a specific HTML, and that includes `<button>` tags. It seems with your code <button> is not working

Comment: @TusharShahi what would that button do?

Comment: @TusharShahi I updated my answer with a workaround but doesn't seem to work very well, maybe using [decorators](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-decorators) would be a better option, but I'm not sure how would you mix them inside the HTML you are parsing.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs) of react-draft-wysiwyg, there's a dedicated part for using html, cited below. The essential steps are:

1. Use a library that converts html to Draft.js `ContentBlock`.

   - The documentation of react-draft-wysiwyg mentions [html-to-draftjs](https://github.com/jpuri/html-to-draftjs), but you can also use Draft.js built-in [`convertFromHtml`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion/#convertfromhtml).
2. Initialize Draft.js `ContentState` with that `ContentBlock`.
3. Initialize Draft.js `ContentEditor` with that `ContentState`
4. Set react-draft-wysiwyg's `Editor`'s `editorState` with that `ContentEditor` object.

Here are two live examples for achieving that: [1](https://codepen.io/Kiwka/pen/YNYgWa), [2](https://codesandbox.io/s/wvm53oao).

Citation from the [documentation](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs) of react-draft-wysiwyg:

> [draftjs-to-html](https://github.com/jpuri/draftjs-to-html) can be used to convert `RawDraftContentState` to html.
> [html-to-draftjs](https://github.com/jpuri/html-to-draftjs) provides the option to convert HTML generated by react-draft-wysiwyg back to draftJS `ContentState` which can be used to initialize the Editor.
>
> ```
> import React, { Component } from 'react';
> import { EditorState, convertToRaw, ContentState } from 'draft-js';
> import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
> import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';
> import htmlToDraft from 'html-to-draftjs';
>  
> class EditorConvertToHTML extends Component {
>  constructor(props) {
>    super(props);
>    const html = '<p>Hey this <strong>editor</strong> rocks </p>';
>   const contentBlock = htmlToDraft(html);
>   if (contentBlock) {
>     const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlock.contentBlocks);
>     const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
>     this.state = {
>       editorState,
>     };
>   }
> }
>
> onEditorStateChange: Function = (editorState) => {
>   this.setState({
>     editorState,
>   });
> };
>
> render() {
>   const { editorState } = this.state;
>   return (
>     <div>
>       <Editor
>         editorState={editorState}
>          wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
>         editorClassName="demo-editor"
>         onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
>       />
>       <textarea
>         disabled
>         value={draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))}
>       />
>     </div>
>   );
> }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think this does exactly what I am expecting. I need to able to add custom HTML into the editor. That includes `<button>` tags. Here even `<a>` tags, are going in a `p`.

Comment: @TusharShahi, for `<a>`, you'll have to use decorators, see in the examples I linked to. As for `<button>`, will after check if that's even possible.

Comment: @TusharShahi, just to clarify: Do you want a `<button>` in the editor's toolbar or in its text area?

Comment: Any update on this? I am trying to achieve the exact same thing!